# Assigning an array count to a tableviewcell label

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a posts array in which I'm returning all the posts from a PHP file. I'm trying to assign the number of posts to a label in a tableview cell. However, when I assign the number of posts to a label, I'm getting a nil value. Can anyone help with this?

```
var posts = [AnyObject]()
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return posts.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! InfoCell

        print(posts.count)

        cell.PostsLbl.text = String(posts.count)

        return cell 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is the array populated from the response of a network request? If so, you are most probably trying to use the array before the asynchronous network request would finish execution. However, without more context, it is impossible to tell for sure. Please include the declaration of `posts` and all code where you are actually modifying it.

Comment: I've included the declaration of posts. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I'm getting a nil value"*? What exactly are you seeing in this `InfoCell` in the first section of your table view?

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 please include all code used to modify `posts` as well.

Comment: @rmaddy I've edited the code to display what i;m seeing in info cell. When I load the viewcontroller, the app is crashing because of a nil value. When I print posts.count, it's printing 0.

Comment: @DávidPásztor all code used to modify posts is posted. I just want to assign my posts label the value of posts.count

Comment: If your app is crashing, you need to fix that obviously. If you don't know how, then update your question to be about the crash with all relevant details.

Comment: @rmaddy , the app is crashing because cell.PostsLbl.text = String(posts.count) is unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. This is why I'm having trouble with this question. If posts.count is returning 8 posts in 8 different tableview cells, I don't know why cell.postsLbl.text is returning 0 as it's value. This is what I was seeking help on.

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 there is no single line of code in which you would be actually __modifying__ `posts`. You are only accessing it. The error you get most probably means that you didn't connect the `IBOutlet` to your `InfoCell` class properly.

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 If your app is crashing trying to set a value on your InfoCell then how can you see the cell displaying 0 posts? That's a contradiction. Anyway, Dávid is probably correct about the cause of the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy If i delete cell.PostsLbl.text = String(posts.count), which is making my app crash, I'm still running this line of code: print(posts.count). It is printing a value of 0. That's the only thing I have a question on. I'm not sure why it's printing this value, when my tableview is returning 8 posts.

Comment: What do you mean by, “My tableview is returning 8 posts? The tableview does return anything. It uses your data source, the ‘posts’ array which is clearly empty.

Comment: @Jim false, func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return posts.count
    }
} is returning 8 posts in my tableview

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 well, I’m assuming that based on the fact that you said ‘print(posts.count)’ prints 0. It’s not clear how you’re determining that posts.count in numberOfRowsInSection is returning 8. I believe what you’re saying, but your answer may help us help you figure this out.

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant details you have put in comments. All that info belongs in your question where people can easily see it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting `posts` async from PHP file and after you get them you reload only the second section.